# error caused by boolean on C( I'm a beginner so please try to be simple)

Tags: c, boolean

I'm trying to use boolean but for some reason, it just gives me an error on Clion.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define bool int
#define true 1
#define false 0
int main() {
    bool isf = true;
    bool ift = false;
    printf("%d\n", isf);
    printf("%d\n", ift);
}
```

```
error code: clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I tried using

```
#include <stdbool.h>
```

but it just ignores it even though I'm on C17.

I also tried defining them which did show that it's not wrong but it showed me an error when I ran it.
I also use Mac and I have Xcode.

I also started learning C a couple days ago so please bear with me.

Correct error code:

```
duplicate symbol '_main' in:
    CMakeFiles/untitled3.dir/main.c.o
    CMakeFiles/untitled3.dir/Second_class.c.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture arm64.
```

Comment: What is the full error message and how are you compiling this program? It works for me here: https://godbolt.org/z/G1WbGW3cx If you try a simple hello world program does that work or are you unable to compile and link anything?

Comment: `#define bool int`?  Who is teaching **that**?!?!  Do not use `#define` to create new types - it is fraught with problems.

Comment: `stdbool.h` should already have `true` and `false` defined.  Don't do it twice.

Comment: "_error code: clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)_" is not the actual error message. The actual error message from the linker should be above it.

Comment: This is not a c question, despite the valuable issues raised in other comments, but a build issue.  You haven't told us anything about you build your program (other than that you are using ninja).  Please revise your tags, too.  `clang your_program.c -o your_program" works for me.

Comment: @Coldsteel48 *I would try to use typedef: 'typedef int bool'* Better to just `#include <stdbool.h>` and use `bool` from there.

Comment: The error is pretty clear. `duplicate symbol '_main'` means you have two functions named `main`. You can't do that. That implies you're compiling more than one file but you've only shown us one of them.

Comment: Ahh I see, thanks for the help! I had another class that used it so it might have stopped it from working. Is there a way to stop it from happening?

Comment: As you are just starting out consider just using vanilla Makefile.  It will be much more transparent to you what is going on instead of using cmake to build a ninja build file to do the build.   `bool`, `true`, `false` are reserved keywords in C 2023 which makes it a bad idea to define those (include stdbool.h instead).

Comment: Clang should already support these without stdbool.h, just compile with `-std=c2x`. It's going to be standard later this year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated by the error message you are linking two files `CMakeFiles/untitled3.dir/main.c.o` and `CMakeFiles/untitled3.dir/Second_class.c.o` that both define the symbol `_main`.

1. You need to either not link both files into the same executable, or
2. Change one of those symbols to a different name

@RetiredNinja says you have two `main()` functions.  I get a differenet error on Linux when I tried to reproduce it:

```
$ clang 1.o 2.o -o 3|& grep main
/usr/bin/ld: 2.o: in function `main':
(.text+0xf0): multiple definition of `main'; 1.o:(.text+0xf0): first defined here
```